# How do I use trigonometric functions?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

I want to know how to use trigonometric functions (an example would be helpful), and what I have to import to use them. Are they in math.h with things like `pow()` and `sqrt()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just want to use things like sin() cos() and such? If so, you don't even need to import math.h as long has you have: `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` in your header file. You can just do something like `double result = cos(12);`

Answer (score 1):

you use basic C function like you would in C, after all Objective-C is a superset of C, not a different language

for example:

```
double root = sqrt(x); //where x is a value
```

and so on..i assume you know how to do that

in any case [here](http://www.codecogs.com/code/computing/c/math.h/index.php) are some examples in C with math function , explanations and examples. These should work in objective c as-is.